# Как запустить отдельный кусок кода в питоне бесконечность раз?

Tags: python

Я писал на python простую "угадайку". randint генерирует случайное число и записывает его в переменную.  Дальше просят пользователя записать число. Если число совпадает, то пользователь победил. Как можно сделать так, чтобы если пользователь проиграл, то ему давали попробовать ещё раз без генерации нового числа?

```
from random import randint

# Сообщаем пользователю диапазон
print("Угадай число от 1 до 50")

# Генерируем случайное число
a = randint(1, 50)

# Пользователь угадывает
b = input("Угадай число: ")

# Сверяемся
if a==int(b):
    print("Красава!")

else:
    print("Неа! Попробуй снова")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это очень просто:

```
# .... начало опущено

while True:   # бесконечный цикл
    # Пользователь угадывает
    b = input("Угадай число: ")
    # Сверяемся
    if a==int(b):
        print("Красава!")
        break   # прерываем бесконечный цикл
    else:
        print("Неа! Попробуй снова")
```

Comment: В данном случае оптимальнее был бы цикл вида `while a!=int(b):` которое позволит сократить код